# Clicked event from MenuItem

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, viewmodel, menuitem

I have an issue when I try to add `OnClicked` function from `MenuItem` to a List inside a Class.
Has anyone here tried this before?

```
private void LoadBodyMenu()
        {
            var bodyMenu = new List<MenuBody>
            {
                new MenuBody
                {
                    Text = "Categories",
                    IconImageSource = IconFont.ShoppingBag,


                }.AddChild(new List<MenuBody>
                    {
                        new MenuBody
                        {
                            Text = "Japonese",
                            IconImageSource = IconFont.List}
                    }),
                new MenuBody
                {
                    Text = "Near",
                    IconImageSource = IconFont.MapMarkedAlt,
                },
                new MenuBody
                {
                    Text = "Famous",
                    IconImageSource = IconFont.Star,
                },
            }.SetColorInMenuList();

            BodyList = bodyMenu.ToObservableCollection();
        }
```

**MenuBody.cs**

```
public class MenuBody : MenuItem
    {
        public MenuBody()
        {
            Child = new List<MenuBody>();
        }

        public Color BackgroundColor { get; set; }

        public List<MenuBody> Child { get; private set; }

        public MenuBody AddChild(List<MenuBody> childrens)
        {
            childrens.SetColorInMenuList();

            var back = new MenuBody
            {
                Text = "Back",
                IconImageSource = IconFont.AngleLeft,
                BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#bdc3c7")
            };

            childrens.Insert(0, back);

            this.Child = childrens;

            return this;
        }
    }
```

My question is how to call Clicked function from `MenuItem` into `MenuBody` List inside `LoadBodyMenu()` ?

So I can create a menu item that contains Text, Icon, and Clicked function inside menu item.

Comment: `MenuItem ` has `Command` property and you can set it for each item. But, how you want to call this property? When you instantiate the `MenuBody` or on selected item?

Comment: What is the relationship between MenuBody and LoadBodyMenu? We do not have the defination of  SetColorInMenuList, SetColorInMenuList and so no. Could you provide more information for me to reproduce?